# elasticsearch query across multiple fields for terms with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building a business search engine to search for business contact details based on a user-inputted query. The information for businesses is stored in an elasticsearch index in the following form:

```
"_source" : {
          "id" : 53,
          "name" : "Judge Pouros",
          "email" : "roob.alberto@example.com",
          "phone" : "+1-783-850-2127",
          "created_at" : "02/10/2019 16:30",
          "updated_at" : "02/10/2019 16:30",
          "travel_agencies" : [
            {
              "id" : 1234,
              "abta" : "A1234",
              "name" : "The Example Travel Agency",
              "address_id" : 27,
              "email" : "zwillms@example.info",
              "comm_rate" : 14.0,
              "travel_agency_type_id" : 1,
              "address" : {
                "id" : 27,
                "line_1" : "Flat 52",
                "line_2" : "Flat 82i\nKaren Circles",
                "town" : "Kimberlyside",
                "county" : "Renfrewshire",
                "country_id" : 189,
                "postcode" : "SM3 9QR",
                "created_at" : "2019-10-02 16:31:01",
                "updated_at" : "2019-10-02 16:31:01",
                "country" : {
                  "id" : 189,
                  "code" : "MF",
                  "name" : "Saint Martin (French part)",
                  "translations" : [
                    {
                      "id" : 189,
                      "locale" : "en",
                      "country_id" : 189,
                      "name" : "Saint Martin (French part)"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
```

Let's say a customer is searching for "example travel renfrewshire". I would expect the above result to be returned. I am current using the following query string:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*example*travel*renfrewshire*"
        }
    }
}
```

But no results are being returned. What I'm trying to do is find documents that contain the terms in the user query with fuzziness to allow for mispelling.

I have thought about matching on specific terms with fuzzyness, but I don't know which terms that users query might match, so I would need to check against all terms.

Is there a simpler query that will do this?

Comment: On which field do you want to search?

Comment: The users term could match any inside the document, so really I need to search against all fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to search the whole document I suggest to use the [multi match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

This will perform a fulltext search on the provided fields.

Your query would look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "example travel renfrewshire",
      "fields" : [ * ] 
    }
  }
}
```

You can also define fuzziness on the match/multi_match query.

Take a look at the [fuzziness documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) for that.

**EDIT:**

As stated in the documentation:

> if no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *. * extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then combined to build a query.

you wouldn't even have to define the fields-setting since it defaults to * (all eligible).

Comment: Keep in mind though that a multi_match on **all** fields is of course slower/more resource-intensive than a query that searches on a defined set of fields (which doesn't mean that Elasticsearch can not handle that!). So maybe you can figure out in which fields the terms will never occurre.